# dev c++, c programme, every character is displaced by a square

Tags: c, cmd

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    while((c=getchar()!=EOF))
    {
        putchar(c);//
    }
}
```

Every character of the output is displaced by '' these sorts of things.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkQZ9.png)

Comment: `c` must be `int`.

Comment: @Raw Don't you think `Dev C++` is obsolete?

Comment: I ran this code in cygwin and then entered some characters on screen but nothing happened. There is no output, the program is stuck.

Comment: @Amit The program isn't stuck but cygwin uses ascii and only the character with ascii value 1 will be printed and that character doesn't have a visible glyph. Try `echo -n Hello | ./this_program | wc -c` and it should print 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong so `c` gets assigned the value of the condition, which is `0` or `1` (`false` or `true`).

What you have now is the same as `c = (getchar() != EOF)` because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Also, use the correct type for `c`, which is `int`:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        putchar(c);//
    }
}
```

Comment: @Raw Glad to hear it! You're welcome!